# How to combine value from XML with a String?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-esb

I have a listener that receives a XML payload. In the following transform I would like to combine a string and a value this XML, but it breaks

This is the XML I receive:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INVOIC02>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <RESULT>12345</RESULT>
  </IDOC>
</INVOIC02>
```

This is my transformation:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
"Result:" ++ (payload.INVOICE.IDOC.RESULT)
```

Apparently I access the payload wrong, I guess. The error message looks like this:

> You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: 
>     1: String ("\n\n  ...)
>     2: Name ("INVOICE")

But it expects one of these combinations:
  (Array, Name)
...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you thought about what the error message is trying to tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the xml doesn't  have the mimetype set. As a workaround set the payload with value payload and set also the mimetype to xml

Comment: Too stupid, I was too focused on the transform. Setting the mime type in the listener solved it... Thanks a lot!